# How to stop Chrome grabbing focus when opening a link from outside Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I catch up on tweets, I like to click interesting links and carry on reading my feed, while the pages linked to load.  That worked fine in Firefox, but now in Chrome, whenever I click a link on a tweet, Chrome grabs the focus.  This is driving me crazy.  How can I stop this?

I'm running XP SP3

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the link with the middle mouse button? It opens a new tab on windows

Answer (score 4):

Check out [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx), I couldn't live without it. It has the option to prevent applications from stealing focus:

[image]

Keep in mind though this doesn't work all the time. Software developers have a lot of nifty tricks that they use to get their windows into focus. I find it works for most things, let me know how it goes with Chrome!

Comment: TweakUI runs only on Windows XP. The OP doesn't say which version of Windows he's running, or even if it's on Windows at all...

Comment: I looked at his other questions. Any question with an operating system related tag was Windows xp or Windows 2003, but TweakUI works on 2003 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the TweakUI suggestion, I'm sure I'll find many, many interesting uses for it, but unfortunately, Chrome still steals the focus.

Comment: That's disappointing. There are many other people looking for similar functionality though as shown here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=50cef989536b7b37&hl=en . Hopefully Google will implement it soon.